# hide / show profile field according to gender

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my view code:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><?php echo $gender;?> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo $w_surname;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo $surname_old; ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

If gender is female then I want to display `$w_surname` and hide `$surname_old`. If gender is male then I want to display `$surname_old` and hide `$w_surname`. It is my profile view.

Comment: you can use simple javascript or jQuery as well..

Comment: i tried that hide show js code . i m giving div to each <td> and trying to hide/show that div on the value of gender.

Comment: Do you need PHP solution??

Comment: i use deepak answer and it solved my problem..

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a ternary if statement - just keeps it tidier.

```
<table>
    <tr><?php echo $gender;?> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo $gender == 'male' ? $surname_old : $w_surname;?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Read more here:
https://www.php.net/ternary

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<table>
    <tr><td><?php echo $gender;?> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo ($gender == 'male') ? '' : $w_surname ; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo ($gender == 'male') ? $surname_old : ''; ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <?php  if ($gender== 'female'):  echo $w_surname; endif;?></td>
<td> <?php  if ($gender== 'male'):  echo  $w_surname,$surname_old; endif;?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```